# Set Start page in Epiphany Web Browser

Tags: raspbian, browser

How do I set the default start page in Epiphany Web Browser?

It is my understanding that this setting could be done in the application GUI in a previous version, but that this feature has been removed.

Comment: Which version would that be ? Any idea if this is the same as gnome epiphany or is it a raspbian-specific version ?

Comment: @don_crissti The version is 'Web 3.8.2' which comes preinstalled with the Raspbian NOOBS setup. "Web" is the new name for the Epiphany browser I believe. It may very well be a Raspberry-specific version, because it's incredibly light in its GUI settings and does not allow setting start page. I thought perhaps there was a way to do this via command-line.

Comment: yeah, I know they call it "web", you appear to be running an older version so you may try with `gsettings set org.gnome.epiphany.homepage-url 'your-url-goes-here'` as they had removed that setting but then re-added it in the [kiosk mode](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-July/msg06084.html). Anyway, there's no such feature on v. 3.18.1 available from arch amd64 repos so there's not much I can help with.